# How do I make the thumbnails appear below the "Add File" button?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some code that will show a thumbnail preview of a file that a user chooses to upload. However, I want it to look more like this:

[image]

I am trying to accomplish a few things with this thumbnail part:

1. To show the thumbnail previews *below* the "Add File" button
2. To show the image as just a smaller image image, a file as a preset image of a file, and a video as the thumbnail for the video with the play symbol over it (see link above for examples)
3. To set a maximum of 5 possible files to be uploaded.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function() {
       $("#uploadFile").on("change", function()
       {
           var files = !!this.files ? this.files : [];
           if (!files.length || !window.FileReader) return; // no file selected, or no FileReader support

           if (/^image/.test( files[0].type)){ // only image file
               var reader = new FileReader(); // instance of the FileReader
               reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]); // read the local file

               reader.onloadend = function(){ // set image data as background of div
                   $("#imagePreview").css("background-image", "url("+this.result+")");
               }
           }
       });
   });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

1) To show the thumbnail previews below the "Add File" button

move your tag with id="imagePreview" bellow your file input

2) To show the image as just a smaller image image, a file as a preset image of a file, and a video as the thumbnail for the video with the play symbol over it (see link above for examples)

set css for your #imagePreview
ex: #imagePreview { width: 100px; height: 100px; }

3) you have no upload functionality provided, so ... no more than 1 field and preview in your code ... so how can i help you?  generally - add a counter as global var and check it ... when it reaches 5 ... hide the file input